# Expectation of a specific random variable on the probability space of $n\times n$ matrices over $\{0,1\}$

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, random-matrices

Let $\mathcal{G}_{n,\frac{1}{2}}$ be the probability space of $n\times n$ matrices over $\{0,1\}$ and each entry of the matrix is independently equal to 1 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and equal to 0 otherwise.

Define a real-valued random variable $X$:
$$X(M)=\prod\limits_{1\leq i,j\leq n}(\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{ik}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{kj}),\ M=(a_{ij})\in \mathcal{G}_{n,\frac{1}{2}}.$$

It is easy to see that $E(X)=0$ when $n$ is odd.

I am interested in the case when $n$ is even. I computed up to $n=2,4,6$ roughly and observed that for most $M$ with no row sum equal to a column sum, $X(M)>0.$

So I guess $E(X)>0$ when $n$ is even, is that right?

Comment: The exact mean would be easy enough to compute up to $n=8$, but why is this an interesting question?

Comment: I think, if it is really always positive for even $n$, this is quite interesting. This may be probably rephrased on the language of Latin squares or something like that.

Comment: @Fedor : OK.  I find overwhelmingly positive values for n=2,4,6,8.  But why?

Comment: @Brendan If I knew, I would already answer.

Comment: Remark. If we denote $a_{ij}=(1+b_{ij})/2$, where $b_{ij}\in \{-1,1\}$, we get $2^{-n^2}$ times corresponding polynomial in $b$'s. Its expectation is nothing but sum of coefficients of monomials having all variables in even degree.